# Maximum value, minimum value of $|x^2 +2x -3 | + 1.5 \ln x $

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the **maximum** and **minimum** value of function:

$$F(x)= |x^2 +2x -3 | + 1.5 \ln x $$ over the interval: $$[\frac{1}{2},4]$$

1. $(21 +3\ln 2, -1.5\ln 2)$
2. $(21 + \ln 1.5,0)$
3. $(21 + 3\ln 2,0)$
4. $(21 +\ln 1.5, -1.5\ln 2)$

My attempt : I  computed $f'(x)$, and saw that there are no critical points in the required interval. So maximum, minimum values should be at boundary points $f(\frac{1}{2}),f(4)$.

But no option match. I need suggestions here. Thanks

Comment: check critical points $$x=0.5\\x=1\\x=4$$because $$|x^2+2x-3|=|(x-1)(x+3)|\\x=1,x=-3 \\$$but x=-3 is not in interval

Comment: How are x=1 and x=4 critical points?

Comment: x=1 is a root for | | , and x=4 is end point in interval

Comment: f(x)=|x-a|  in x=a f'(x) does not exist ,so x=a is a critical point

Comment: @daryakhosrotash thank you very very much. Its solved now